# Problem with importing bootstrap 5 sass variable to my project's sass

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to use Bootstrap 5 variables in my own styles.scss file. 
I've downloaded the whole Bootstrap 5 source code and have it together with my project. 

I've found that in my styles.scss file I should import the following .scss files for it to work (which I do):

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss";
@import "bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss";
@import "bootstrap/scss/_mixins.scss";
```

The order is as they show it on the official Bootstrap page. But each time I get the following error:

```
Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @import "bootstrap5/scss/_functions.scss";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  sass/styles.scss 1:9  root stylesheet
```

It contains only the first line of my imports.
Why is it so? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Is the folder right? `bootstrap5` -> `bootstrap`

Comment: Yes, it's OK. I forgot to change it only here in my question. Sorry 

Comment: The import "bootstrap" only works if its in the same directory or if you are using NPM or a package manager. Is it in the same folder? I need more information to see where the problem is. Please upload an image of your folder structure

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of the `_` from  _**function.scss**